# importing XML values?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, get

Assuming I have a simple XML with only one item...

```
<myXML>
   <valuesItem
      name = 'name'
      age = 'age'
      gender = 'gender'
   />
</myXML>
```

...and want to import only the item's attribute values to be the new values of a jQuery object like this...

```
var myObject = {
        name: 'name',
        age: 'age',
        gender: 'gender'
};
```

...how shoud I proceed ???

I tried to achieve my purpose like this but I had no success so far:

```
var myObject = {};

$.get(myXML.xml, function(xmlData) {
      var xmlValues = {};

      $(xmlData).find('valuesItem').each(function() {
             var $item = $(this);
             xml Values = {
                    name: $item.attr('name'),
                    age: $item.attr('age'),
                    gender: $item.attr('gender')
             };
      });

      $.extend(myObject, xmlValues);
});
```

How can I make public the $.get() return results ?

Comment: ty for the edit Tomalak didn't noticed the errors and i presume I can't use jQUery in the title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are making an ajax call that is asynchronous. Either you use $.ajax and set the call not to be asynch or if you have to use the xml data, you must call a function in the success function of the $.get call.

for example you could do:

```
var myObject = {};

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'myXML.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  async: false, 
  success: function ( xmlData ) {

      $(xmlData).find('valuesItem').each(function() {
             var $item = $(this);
             myObject = {
                    name: $item.attr('name'),
                    age: $item.attr('age'),
                    gender: $item.attr('gender')
             };
      });
  }  
});
//here myObject is set because it waits for the call to finish
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola but this doesn't work !
If you notice in my code myObject is declared outside the get() too...
The logics is the same the only difference is that you tried to assign the new values directly to myObject while in my case i used $.extend to merge two objects...

Comment: yes you are right: the problem is that the $.get() call is asynchronous and so you will have to use $.ajax and make it synchronous i think

Comment: Ok! This is it! The "async" was my issue! Thank you Nicola!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
var myObject = {};

$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'myXML.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function ( data ) {
    myObject = data;
  }  
});
```

**HOWEVER**, if you put the code that handles the xml directly after `$.ajax()` you will run into all sorts of errors because the call will not have completed.

Better that you put all of your logic inside the success function like so..

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'myXML.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function ( data ) {
    //do stuff with data here
    //the variable "data" holds all of your xml, parsed into a JavaScript object
  }  
});
```

as success will not be called untill the server has responded to the request.

**EDIT:** you may be better served doing something like this for your particular usecase.

first define a function that takes an argument `data` and sets up the plugin

```
startPlugin = function ( data ) {
    var newoptions = {};
    newOptions.name = data.myXML.valuesItem.name;
    newOptions.age = data.myXML.valuesItem.age;
    newOptions.gender = data.myXML.valuesItem.gender;

    //start the plugin here with newOptions
}
```

then, pass that function to ajax as the success callback.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'myXML.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: startPlugin  
});
```

also in `$.ajax()` you can set `async` to false to make the request synchronous but that's considered bad practice.

Comment: ty Greg!
I'll try this out... Maybe stucking on the $.get function and try to figure out what I did wrong isn't the best solution! I'll let you know!

Comment: @RArtDesign `$.get()` is just shorthand for `$.ajax()` with a few of the paarameters filled out. but when you do it the long way you can set the `dataType` to xml which is nice because then jQuery does the xml parsing for you and you can just call your members like this... `data.myXML.valuesItem.name`

Comment: Well . . . I get the same result as using $.get... "undefined"

Comment: The real purpose of this question is that I just wanted to extend the defaults = {} of a jQuery plugin importing some external data using XML... but as far as I can't make the retrieved data public I'm out of ideas XD . . .

Comment: @RArtDesign ok, I think I've made some edits which will give you the functionality you're looking for